# Parent window is getting closed on refresh

Tags: javascript

My requirement is that on close of parent window child windows should also close. But now the problem is that even when I refresh my parent window the windows get closed. I dont want that refresh to close the windows. My code is

```
            function closeEditorWarning(){

     for (var i=0;i<childWindow.length;i++) {
           if (childWindow[i] && !childWindow[i].closed)    childWindow[i].close();
     }
    self.close();
     }

          window.onbeforeunload = closeEditorWarning;
```

Comment: Why do you refresh the parent window?  Can you use ajax instead of refresh?

Answer (score 0):

On browser refresh page gets unloaded and then it loads again. As you are using "onbeforeunload" it gets called before unload, hence "closeEditorWarning" method is getting called. To resolve this issue you can disable browser refresh.

Answer (score 0):

If the child window is webpage of your own, you may try to put code into child webpages instead, checking if the parent is still there periodically through cookies, seeing if it is kept "alive" or not

Answer (score 0):

I removed `self.close();` and it's workng fine now.